# 404 Not Found. File exists (mounted)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, cifs

First off, I will update this post with any information you may need, but since I have no idea where to begin, I will try to summarize the issue. Please just ask if you want to see something.

I'm having issues with retrieving files on my web. When the link is clicked it returns `404 Not Found`, even though the file exists and was working just yesterday. I haven't made any changes and can't figure out what could be causing this..

My site is running on an Ubuntu server. The files are located on a Windows server that is mounted (using CIFS) onto the web.

Here is output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem                          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1                            38G   11G   26G  30% /
udev                                488M  4.0K  488M   1% /dev
tmpfs                               100M  592K   99M   1% /run
none                                5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                                498M     0  498M   0% /run/shm
//10.0.1.1/quotefiles               2.0T  1.1T  1.0T  51% /home/site/mnt/quotefiles
//10.0.1.1/eng                      2.0T  1.1T  1.0T  51% /home/site/mnt/cad
//10.0.1.1/eng/x_tps_design         2.0T  1.1T  1.0T  51% /home/site/mnt/design
//10.0.1.1/data/program_management  2.0T  1.7T  393G  81% /home/site/mnt/workorders
//10.0.1.1/eng/cust_stds            2.0T  1.1T  1.0T  51% /home/site/mnt/stds
//10.0.1.1/engdata/incoming         2.0T  1.7T  393G  81% /home/site/mnt/incoming
//10.0.1.1/ftp                      2.0T  1.7T  393G  81% /home/site/mnt/ftp
//10.0.1.1/jobs                     2.0T  1.8T  249G  88% /home/site/mnt/jobs
```

And output of `ls -la /home/site/mnt/`:

```
drwxrwxr-x 11 site site    4096 Mar 30 09:40 .
drwxr-xr-x 29 site site    4096 Jul 14 11:05 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 site site    4096 Mar 30 09:36 backups
drwxr-xr-x  1 site site  106496 Jul  9 15:49 cad
drwxr-xr-x  1 site site  131072 Jul  6 07:56 design
drwxr-xr-x  1 www-data site   65536 Jun 29 12:51 ftp
drwxr-xr-x  1 site site   49152 Jul 14 08:33 incoming
drwxr-xr-x  1 site site  262144 Jul 14 10:11 jobs
drwxr-xr-x  1 site site 3211264 Jul  2 10:50 quotefiles
drwxr-xr-x  1 site site   16384 Jul  9 07:44 stds
drwxr-xr-x  1 site site    8192 Jan 20 09:00 workorders
```

The owner / group of these folders is correct. That is how they were set up and everything was working fine until this morning..

Perhaps the strangest part is that I am able to upload files into the Windows server using the web, but that same file cannot be retrieved....

Any help / tips really appreciated ! Thanks

EDIT: access.log doesn't seem like it has anything, it's pretty much filled with this over and over:

```
192.168.1.52 - - [13/Jul/2015:09:02:22 -0400] "GET /logo.png HTTP/1.1" 404 504 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Thunderbird/31.7.0 Lightning/3.3.2"
```

In error.log, however, I found this and some others similar to it (along with other irrelevant errors)..

```
[Tue Jul 14 11:36:35 2015] [error] [client 10.0.20.5] PHP Warning:  opendir(/home/site/mnt/jobs/...): failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /home/site$
```

Pretty sure it's just saying that it can't find the directory, but it's there if I navigate to it through SSH (/home/site/mnt/jobs/...)..